# Regex that finds specific emails

Tags: regex

This is my String:

```
test1@test.com
$test2@test.com
!test3@test.com
:test4@test.com
```

What i want now is to get all emails that do not start with colon and remove the leading character. So this is the ouput i want:

```
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3@test.com
```

This is what i thought should work

```
[^:][a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?
```

But not i still get the email with the colon, it is just cutting out the colon symbol itself.

Comment: If we focus on just fixing this pattern, try something like `\b(?<!:)[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_\-+.]*@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?\b`

Comment: Another idea to use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with something like [`^[^\w:]?(\w\S*?@\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xbgCqH/1) ([Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurWMFWQakktbjE0AFE6iXn58bkqYCYRkgCiiCmMZKAFYhpAhdQ4uIqKMrMK9EoStVLy8xLSczJ0ShS17DP1YyLjospt4q114gpjwnWsneICdbWVNdRKNbU/P8fAA))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... What i want now is to get all emails that do not start with colon and remove the leading character. ..."*

You can use the following pattern.

```
\b(?<!:)[^@\s]+@[^.]+\.[^\s]+\b
```

- `\b(?<!:)`, a *word boundary* not preceded by a `:`
- `[^@\s]+@`, all characters up to `@`
- `[^.]+\.`, all characters up to `.`
- and `[^\s]+\b`, all characters up to a *word boundary*

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great too :) And thanks also for the explanation, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

Look for common email regex pattern, for example [^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4}$](https://regexr.com/3e48o)

Step 2.

Adjust above pattern by adding your rule - add `[^:a-z]?` to optionally match character other than `:` and other than letter, to not consume first letter of email address.

Step 3.

Wrap email pattern in `()` which will put matched email inside capturing group:

```
^[^:a-z]?([\w\-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$)
```

Replacement pattern would be `$1`, which will be first capturing group containing email without special character at the beginning.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0mWYh/1)

Answer (score 0):

The `[^:][a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+` part matches and *consumes* any char other than `:` as the first matched char, and then matches one or more word, `-`, `+` or `.` chars. It means it will still return those matches after `:`, but without the first char.

Since you want to find email-like substrings in a longer text that are not immediately preceded with a `:` char, you can rely on a pattern like

```
\b(?<!:)[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_\-+.]*@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CWEWvv/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!:)` - immediately before, there should be no `:`
- `[a-z0-9_]` - a word char (excluding capital letters if no case modifier is used)
- `[a-z0-9_\-+.]*` - zero or more lowercase letters, digits, `_`, `-`, `+` or `.` chars
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-z0-9\-]+` - one or more lowercase letters, digits, `-`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[a-z]{2,4}` - two, three or four lowercase letters
- `(?:\.[a-z]{2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and then two lowercase letters.
- `\b` - a word boundary